Berry-Esseen Bounds for Summation of CDF
Consider the Binomial Random Variable $X \sim Bin(n, p)$.
I want to approximate $\sum_{x = 0}^a F(x)$ using the Normal, where $F(x)$ denotes the $Bin(n, p)$ CDF.
We know that using Berry-Esseen theorem, we have bounds for the difference between the normalized version of the CDF and $\Phi(x)$, where $\Phi(x)$ is the normal CDF.
However, summing this over all values of $a$ provides too loose a bound. Are there any bounds asymptotically tighter than this?
